# How to know if a struct or pointer to struct implements an interface

Tags: go, reflection

I need to know if either the struct or the pointer to that struct implements a given interface.

```
// You can edit this code!
// Click here and start typing.
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
 var a A = A{
  i: 5,
 }
 Serialize(a)
 Serialize(&a)
}

type Serializable interface {
 //Serialize() string
 //Deserialize(string)

 Serializebyte() []byte
 Deserializebyte(b []byte) (bytesRead int)
}

type A struct {
 i int
}

func (*A) Serializebyte() []byte {
 return []byte{0x00}
}

func (*A) Deserializebyte(b []byte) (bytesRead int) {
 return 0
}

func Serialize(objInt interface{}) []byte {
 // this doesn't work

 switch v := (objInt).(type) {
 case Serializable:
  fmt.Printf("I'm Serializable\n")
  return v.Serializebyte()
 }

 fmt.Printf("I'm not Serializable\n")
 return []byte{0x00}
}

// this other way also dont work
func Serialize2(objInt interface{}) []byte {
// this doesn't work
    _, isSerializable := objInt.(Serializable)
    if isSerializable{
        fmt.Printf("I'm Serializable\n")
        return objInt.(Serializable).Serializebyte()
}

    fmt.Printf("I'm not Serializable\n")
    return []byte{0x00}
}



// Stdout:
// I'm not Serializable
// I'm Serializable
```

**Edit:**
You can run the code above to see what I mean.

Because `(*A)` implements `Serializable` not `A`, the assertion above does not pass but I want to know if either `(*A)` implements `Serializable` or `A` implements it.

Why do I want that? Because if I can do that, the programmers do not need to know how `Serializable` works. If not the programers should always need to pass a pointer to `Serializable` and implement `Serializable` in the struct pointer rather than the struct itself.

Comment: Why doesn't a type assertion like `s, ok := obj.(Serializable)` provide everything you need to know?  The assertion succeeds for some type `*T` if the methods are on type `T` or `*T`.

Comment: No, It only works if you pass `*T` to the function, otherwise it does not implements `Serializable`.

Comment: So, you need a `Serializable` in `Serialize`? Then why did you write `interface{}` in the method signature? Just change it to `Serializable` and let the compiler do all the work for you.

Comment: @Peter because when is not `Serializable` , `Serialize`  use reflection to serialize the object, but if the object is `Serializable` then that means that the object has special rules for serializing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually a bad idea to use `*T` when the user gives you `T`. All modifies on `*T` will **NOT** take effect on user's data.

But if that is what you really want, you can use reflect.

```
func testFool(a interface{}) bool {
    if _, ok := a.(Fool); ok {
        return true
    }
    t := reflect.PtrTo(reflect.TypeOf(a))
    FoolType := reflect.TypeOf((*Fool)(nil)).Elem()
    return t.Implements(FoolType)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/rqJe5_KAP6e

EDIT：If you need to make use of that method with pointer reciever, you can use `reflect.Value` instead of `reflect.Type`. However, it makes an extra copy of the param.

```
func testFool(a interface{}) bool {
    if _, ok := a.(Fool); ok {
        return true
    }
    t := reflect.TypeOf(a)
    v := reflect.New(t)
    v.Elem().Set(reflect.ValueOf(a))
    ptrA := v.Interface()
    if foo, ok := ptrA.(Fool); ok {
        foo.Foo()
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

It is hackable to write a copy-free version code by using `refelct.NewAt` and ·reflect.Value.InterfaceData`. But it is highly un-recommended: It will very likely break your future code and is hard to maintain; It uses unsafe package under the hood.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes ;) . I need it because `Serializebyte()` can be inefficient if it copied all the object and I'm not really changing the object I just need to access its data without copying all over again.

Comment: It works but I can't manage  to run the function, it always panics, here is an example of what I try to do https://play.golang.org/p/Fw6Iw2ds1Fv

Comment: Great now the code is working like a charm and I see the trick there, you create a new pointer and then copy the values of the original object to the pointer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
func Serialize(objInt interface{}) []byte {
    switch v := objInt.(type) {
    case Serializable:
        return v.Serializebyte()
    }

    // do stuf on object that do not implement Serializebyte
}
```

https://tour.golang.org/methods/16